# How can access local file from localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, localhost

I'm developing a web application with spring boot. In application, I upload a file and copy to the local folder after that file absolute path is saved in the database. So I have file and I know where it is but I can't reach it in localhost. I know in spring has a static folder for static files but I don't want to copy a file because I will use this data in other applications.

For example:

Local file location: `/Users/user/data/image.png`

I want to reach like that: `http://localhost:8080/data/image.png`

---

**Edit: I find the solution.** I used `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` for this.

```
String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName(FileController.class,"serveFile",resource.getFilename()).build().toString();
```

it's return right value of controllers method.

Method:

```
@GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> serveFile(@PathVariable String filename) {

        Resource file = storageService.loadAsResource(filename);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"").body(file);
    }
```

Comment: you can create a controller that reads the file from the actual location, but map it through a `@RequestMapping` as you described in your `localhost:8080` form

Comment: Use classpath to get file from data folder and move to your  absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is with url you are using. Change it to:

```
@RequestMapping("/data/{filename:.+}")
```

this will work.

Comment: This is not my question also I find the solution.